# Why doesn't that work?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.proces_colm').click(function(){
    var colm = $(this);
colm.next().slideToggle('normal', function(){ 
colm.css('background-position','left bottom');
});
colm.css('background-position','left top');
});
```

html:

```
<div class="proces_colm">x</div><!--proces_colm-->
<div class="proces_colm_sub">xx</div><!--proces_colm_sub>
```

css:

```
.proces_colm{float:left; width:100%; height:31px; position:relative; margin-top:10px; 
background:#cad7ea url(images/procesArrow.png) left top no-repeat; text-align:left;   
cursor:pointer;}

.proces_colm_sub{float:left; width:100%; position:relative; height:auto; 
background:#add8e6; text-align:left; font-size:1.30em;}
```

As clicking on column back change background position back to 'top', but it keeps b.position bottom!

Comment: where is `html` and `css` code ???

Comment: Can you write HTML code?

Comment: it should be `$('.proces_colm', this).`

Comment: also you are trying to do what `toggle()` was doing with `click`

Comment: Have a look at the **documentation of `.click`**: http://api.jquery.com/click/. It doesn't say anywhere that `.click` accepts multiple functions and toggles between them.  What exactly are you trying to do? The more information we have, the better we can help you!

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I think it should be just `$(this).next()...`. `this` already appears to be a `.proces_colm` element.

Comment: @FelixKling the markup was not there when I posted it.... just went with the syntax

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Me too. Since the event handler is bound to `$('.proces_colm')`, `this` already refers to a `.proces_colm` element and hence `$('.proces_colm', this)` seemed incorrect (unless you thought that the elements are nested).

Comment: @FelixKling I thought they were nested... now it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you put the callback at the wrong position, 2nd param as the slideToggle, not click

<strike>$('.proces_colm').click(function() {</strike>

```
    var ele = $(this);

    ele.next().slideToggle('normal', function() {

        ele.css('background-position', 'left top');
    });

    ele.css('background-position', 'left bottom');
});
```

This might not work as you expected, but I think it can help figure out how.

```
$('.proces_colm').click(function() {

    var ele = $(this), nxt = ele.next();
    //stop the animation firstly
    ele.next().stop(true).slideToggle('normal', function() {

        if (nxt.is(':hidden')) {

            ele.css('background-position', 'left top');

        } else {

            ele.css('background-position', 'left bottom');

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I got your point, indeed! and it works but what is the reason then result of clicking on colm second time is b.position bottom? it s supposed to turn back to b.position top.. I edited my js code up there.

Comment: Well ele.next().slideToggle is async, so it might not finished when the next click comming, I think it 's better to use css, wait a sec, I'll improve the answer

Comment: See the answer now, it'll make sure the background-position sync with the display status of ele.next

Answer (score 0):

Work Around:

```
$('.proces_colm').click(function(){
    var colm = $(this);
colm.next().slideToggle('normal', function(){ 
    colm.css('background-position','0% 100%');
});
    colm.css('background-position','0% 0%');
});
```